# How to make Windows pop up like Windows 8 in Windows 10?

Tags: windows

I have been using a library PC running Windows 8 and I kind of liked how the windows were showing up. When you switch between programs, the new windows uses a pop up enter animation like it starts small and expands to cover the whole screen and when minimized, it is like a pop out exit animation where it reduces in width and height until it is out view. Is there any way of achieving the same on Windows 10, would really love to make my Windows behave that way when I start them or when I switch between programs.
You can see the transitions I encountered on the library PC from this Imgur link [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jAvaF.jpg). Any wat to achieve the same transitions on Windows is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you have not installed some software on Windows 8 for that?

Comment: No, actually the animation is like the window effect when you click the start menu of Windows 8, the enter animation. Is there a third party software I can use to define the animations?

Comment: Windows animation options are found at *Start > Adjust the appearance and performance of Windows*.

Comment: I adjusted the options to appearance and window enter animations are in the blink of a second, no animations

Comment: It's called a Toast Alert.

Comment: @spikey_richie, how do I make my windows behave that way?

Comment: Whatever I experienced on that PC made me feel inadequate because windows on mine are not so cool

Comment: I am going to attach a video or a gif to this post

Comment: Are you referring to Tablet mode? Where all apps go full screen?

Comment: I t could be, I will update the post with a link to the way windows gain focus and lose them

Comment: If it's not natively supported in Windows 10, it, and several other animation types, can be set via Stardock's [WindowsFX](https://www.stardock.com/products/windowfx/) [$10] _(if considering purchasing, review [other Stardock programs](https://www.stardock.com/products/), as you get all of them with an [Object Desktop](https://www.stardock.com/products/odnt/) subscription for $40, whereas purchasing them individually is significantly more expensive)_

Comment: @JW0914, okay will buy the software, Microsoft drops a very good window animation and, anyway let me buy WindowsFX and thanks :))

Comment: @JW0914, please post an answer as the Stardock software has exceeded my expectations. you deserve the points

Answer (score 0):

This is likely controlled by your Performance preferences. Open the Performance Options dialogue, and ensure you have the `Animate` & `Fade` options enabled

[image]

Comment: it is checked, it looks like I need to downgrade to windows 10